# Sending special ascii char through usb converter rs232

Tags: c++

I need send some special chars through usb rs232 converter to my device.

b.cpp:

```
unsigned char message[] = "ÀwLO~P";

int main(void) {

   openPort(port, 9600);
   int i = 0;

//   while (i < 2000) {
   writePort(message);
   char* readChar = readPort();
   cout <<"rr "<< static_cast<string>(readChar);

 //     i++;
//     sleep(5);
// }

closePort();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

My writePort function:

```
void writePort(unsigned char* message) {
int e;
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   e = message[i];
   printf("Out: %d", e) ;
    write(tty_fd, &message[i], 6);
    usleep(10);
 }
}
```

Beacose my first sign is out of range normal char "À" 192 i see in printf that it's divide to two bytes.

printf output:

```
 Out: 195 Out: 128 Out: 119 Out: 76 Out: 79 Out: 126 Out:80
```

How can i send that's specyfic char?

Comment: Why `7` in `i < 7`?  I'd expect `int i = 0; message[i]; i++`

Comment: Off topic: The magic numbers are killing you. For example, why 6 here? `write(tty_fd, &message[i], 6);`

Comment: À isn't valid ASCII so check the character encoding of your file.  Likely it isn't ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting non-ASCII characters into a C source file is risky. If you want a specific byte sequence, write it out as an array of numbers:

```
unsigned char message[] = { 192, 119, 76, 79, 126, 80 };
```

Or as a string with hexadecimal escapes:

```
unsigned char message[] = "\xc0wLO~P";
```